# Compare old values against the new values of Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with several fields, one of which is "counter", that gets changed constantly. When the form is edited I need to track if some fields are changed and set the "counter" field  to the number of modified fields up on submission. For example, if the old value of counter is 10 and field1, field2 and field3 are modified, then on form submit counter should be incremented to 13.

Below is what I'm attempting to do just for one field but its not working correctly. I also need to check not only one field but a few other fields too. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var oldVal = getOldValue("field1");
    var oldCounter = parseInt(getOldValue("Counter"));
    var curCounter;

    $('field1').change(function(){
        var newVal= $(this).val();

            if(oldVal.val() == newVal.val()){
                curCounter = oldCounter +1;
                setField("Counter", parseInt(curCounter));
            }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is incorrect. It fires when the value has changed (`.change()`), yet you are checking if the value is the same through `if(oldVal.val() == newVal.val())`

Also, `.val()` is a method of the jQuery object, so unless the function `getOldValue()` returns a jQuery object, your `if` statement is probably not going to do what you're expecting it to do.

What I'd do is store the oldValues of the form fields inside a `data` attribute of the formfield, so you can easily access it from within the `.change()` event, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var oldCounter = parseInt(getOldValue("Counter"), 10); // use the second argument '10' here or you might get strange results
    var curCounter = oldCounter;


    $('.field').each(function() {
        // store the old value
        $(this).data("oldValue", getOldValue($(this).attr("id")));
    })
    .change(function(){
        // compare values, increase counter if it is different than the original value
        if($(this).data("oldValue") != $(this).val()) {
           curCounter++;
           setField("Counter", curCounter);
        }
    });

});
```

Untested code but you get the gist, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

3 things i've noticed

*. you are checking the newVal's value twice, it should be something like

`var newVal = $(this).val();
if (oldVal == newVal).....`

*. for the oldValue variable you can just do `var oldVal=$('#filed1_id').val();` this will be much simpler and will get you the value needed and not the object, this is simpler to handle.

*.  you say you need to check for change on submission but you're checking on change, change it to which means you'll be checking more often when you need to.

and again, it will be nice to know what's getOldValue does.
good luck

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know whether the user modified any fields when the form is submitted. It would be easiest to use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to keep track of which fields have changed from their original value. As other posters have mentioned your code calls `.val()` redundantly, incorrectly uses `==` instead of `!=`, and might not be using jQuery objects correctly.

This fiddle should address your issues: http://jsfiddle.net/EYjxP/